# Matlab running an external program finishes abruptly with this weird status code: -1.0737e+09

Tags: matlab

I can't run and external command using system or dos function in matlab, it ends with a weird status code!

```
‍‍system(dosCommand)

ans =

  -1.0737e+09
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It has been answered here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/408044-what-is-the-difference-between-a-system-call-from-matlab-using-system-and-a-command-in-a-cmd-ter#answer_354381

You need to run `system('path')` to see the matlab dir on path

```
>> system('path');
PATH=C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2022b\bin\win64;; # shortened for brevity
>>
```

Then run your command like this:

```
>> system(['set path=%path:C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2022b\bin\win64;=% & ' dosCommand]);
```